# Being asked for password in Ventura on Network settings

Tags: macos, network, security, ventura, touch-id

I'm using `Ventura 13.4.1 (c)`, on a number of Macs.

All MacBook Pro laptops, I change my network settings regularly for work (DNS, etc). For some reason on one of the Macs I get this popup each time I even open network settings, without making a change, just by pressing "OK".

[image]

I'm the owner, so I have the password/fingerprint to unlock, but it's just strange.
Settings are the same on my other Macs.

Any idea why this is constantly prompted?

EDIT, current settings:
[image]

Comment: Settings > Wi-Fi > Advanced... > Require administrator authorization to change networks > [off]

Comment: @LincD. thanks for the reply, already Off on all Macs, in fact, the touchID settings and the whole network security settings are identical.

Comment: Added a pic to show current settings, in fact the only difference is that one Mac has a VPN as part of the network

Comment: Figured it out, it was "Require a password to change system wide settings" in privacy and security advanced.